# Delete directory with pattern in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I've been trying to create a clean task that will remove some directories in my file tree.  I don't want to use the exact path to the directory since it may vary by the flavor.

This works by removing all the files, but I'd like the directory tree gone as well:

```
task cleanAll(type: Delete, dependsOn: 'clean') {

   delete fileTree('src').matching { include '**/obj/**' }
   delete fileTree('src').matching { include '**/jniLibs/**' }
   delete fileTree('src').matching { include '**/gen/**' }
}
```

I've tried this as well, but it's really not a `Delete` task and only removes some of the directories:

```
task cleanAll(type: Delete, dependsOn: 'clean') {
   def deleteList = [ 'obj', 'jniLibs' ]
   def dirsToDelete = []
   def tree = fileTree('src').visit {
      def File f = it.file
      if ( f.isDirectory() && deleteList.contains(f.name)) {
         dirsToDelete << f
      }
   }
   dirsToDelete.each { dir -> dir.delete() }
}
```

I've read the docs and searched quite a bit but I feel I'm missing something easy.

** EDIT **

Just a sample folder structure

```
app/src/main
app/src/flavor1/obj
app/src/flavor1/jniLibs
```

But flavor1 folder is not hardcoded into the Gradle script.  These Android flavors are added dynamically by the presence of the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing.  Simply, any sub-directory with matching names will be removed.

```
import groovy.io.FileType

class DeleteDir extends DefaultTask {
   def baseDir = "."
   def deleteMe(Object... targets) {
       def directoryList = []
       def baseDirectory = new File(baseDir).eachFileRecurse(FileType.DIRECTORIES) {
           if ( targets.contains(it.name) ) {
               directoryList << it
           }
       }
       directoryList.each { dirObj -> 
           if ( dirObj.exists() ) {
               println "Removing directory: $dirObj"
               dirObj.deleteDir()
           }
       }
   }
}

task hello( type: DeleteDir) {
    baseDir = '.'
    deleteMe 'obj', 'gen', 'jniLibs'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use:

```
task cleanAll(type: Delete, dependsOn: 'clean') {
  delete 'jniObjects', 'obj', 'gen'
}
```

?

Comment: That did not work.  The folders mentioned are somewhere below in the file tree, they are not direct child folders from the Android src directory.